# Is there a native function to generate an array index based on column value?

Tags: php

I would like to know if there is a native function in PHP for generating an array index based on one of it's column value.

For example this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [title] => Product 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [title] => Product 2
        )

)
```

Would become this:

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [title] => Product 1
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [title] => Product 2
        )

)
```

Comment: Why not just use the 'id' value as the index when you put the stuff into the array?

Comment: There is no native way to magically do that, however, with few code, you can achieve to your result

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I realize now that i've made a mistake in the question title, i wanted to know if there is a NATIVE function to do this or as close as possible for code efficienty. Of course implementing it with a loop is trivial. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can use [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function to achieve this by passing the index parameter which is the 3rd parameter, which is `id` in your case.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$arr = array
(
    array
        (
            'id' => 5,
            'title' => 'Product 1'
        ),

    array
        (
            'id' => 12,
            'title' => 'Product 2'
        )
);

print_r(array_column($arr,NULL,'id'));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/MU2SK

Comment: Thanks, that's great. No trouble implementing it manually of course but i figured there might be a more code-efficient way.

Comment: @Sodium Glad to help :) Yes, it does exist like I mentioned and why reinvent the wheel.